# check date_join of user with specific datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime, if-statement

im new in python and django. i want check user.date_join with specific datetime but i dont know what is correct syntax.

for more information : i have a SignIn  function in view.py and i want check `if user.date_join < yyyy/mm/dd` i do something .

view.py:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

if request.method == "POST":
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if user.date_joined < (yyyy/mm/dd):  # <==== here i have problem
                       #do smt
        else:
           #do smt
    else:
      #blah blah
else:
   #blah blah
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing dates or date objects in Python is very easy. 
The basic comparison operators **(==, !=, <>, >, <, >=, <=)** are overloaded for the datetime object, so comparing dates is very intuitive and quick.

try this

```
if user.date_joined.date() < datetime.datetime('%Y/%d/%m'):
   #
```

Comment: tnx for reply.when i use this condition i got error : `TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)` then i change it to `if user.date_joined.date() < datetime.datetime(2019,10,10)` and this error appear `TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date`

Comment: i change it a little bit and its work now . i import `date` instead  `timedate`and use this condition : `if user.date_joined.date() < date(2019,10,10)` . its work now.tnxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Assuming **user.date_joined** is already a Datetime object
You can do a comparison in DateTime objects. Convert your (yyyy/mm/dd) format in Datetime object and do the comparison

```
import datetime

// Let's say you need to check if user is joined 8 days back or more

if user.date_joined < datetime.datetime.now()- datetime.timedelta(days=7):
    // your logic

in your case:

if user.date_joined < datetime.datetime('%Y/%d/%m')
    // your logic
```